# Server-side implementation for a chip-capturing board game

Tags: c++, game, server, sfml

I am currently coding a game in C++ with a network connection. The game consists of two players on a game-board who compete for capturing chips. I am aware that this program is a little bit useless since there is no way to go back and forth connecting players. I will be refactoring the network code, so it looks like a real server. I am just wondering if my code is readable at least. I provide the code for the server side.

```
// Serversidegame.cpp : Handles requests from client side.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>  
#include <sstream>
#include "utility.h"

std::string PLAYER_MOVE_REQUEST = "PLAYER_MOVE";
std::string CHIP_CREATION_REQUEST = "CHIP_CREATION";
std::string CHIP_DELETION_REQUEST = "CHIP_DELETION";

/*This function handles chip creation on board. Since the dimensions of the game board is 8 X 7, this function
generates 15 random numbers between 0 and 56 and then these numbers are mapped to the right coordinates on the
game board. Once these random numbers are generated, the function triggers a boolean variable  which 
wakes up an if statement in another thread. This if statement sends a packet to the client with the generated
random numbers which are tranlated to graphics by the client side.*/

void handle_chip_creation(std::string* data, bool* send_chip_creation, game_state* gameState) {
    int NUMBER_OF_RANDS = 15; //Number of chips on board
    int rand_number; 
    std::string position_chips;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int mapped_chip_xpos;
    int mapped_chip_ypos;
    std::cout << "generating board numbers" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_RANDS; i++) {
        std::stringstream string_rand;
        rand_number = rand() % 55 + 0;
        std::cout << rand_number << std::endl;
        string_rand << rand_number;
        position_chips += string_rand.str();
        position_chips += "_";
        mapped_chip_xpos = rand_number % 8;
        mapped_chip_ypos = rand_number / 8;
        gameState->set_chip_pos(mapped_chip_xpos, mapped_chip_ypos);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    *(data) = position_chips;
    std::cout << "sending coordinates" << *(data) << std::endl;
    *(send_chip_creation) = true;
}

/*This function handles the deletion of a chip if a move request results in collision*/

void handle_chip_deletion(int chip_xpos, int chip_ypos, listen_param param) {
    *(param.chip_pos_x) = chip_xpos;
    *(param.chip_pos_y) = chip_ypos;
    *(param.send_chip_deletion) = true;
}

/*Handles move request. Check for possible collisions from both players. Check whether the board is empty or not
after a player-move request*/
void handle_plmove_request(game_packet packet, listen_param param) {
    if (packet.player_move == "u1")
        param.player1->moveUp();
    else if (packet.player_move == "d1")
        param.player1->moveDown();
    else if (packet.player_move == "l1")
        param.player1->moveLeft();
    else if (packet.player_move == "r1")
        param.player1->moveRight();
    else if (packet.player_move == "u2")
        param.player2->moveUp();
    else if (packet.player_move == "d2")
        param.player2->moveDown();
    else if (packet.player_move == "l2")
        param.player2->moveLeft();
    else if (packet.player_move == "r2")
        param.player2->moveRight(); 

    double delete_xpos;
    double delete_ypos;

    if (param.gameState->check_collision(param.player1) == true) {
        delete_xpos = param.player1->get_xpos();  
        delete_ypos = param.player1->get_ypos();
        param.gameState->unset_chip_pos(delete_xpos, delete_ypos);
        handle_chip_deletion(delete_xpos,delete_ypos,param);
        *(param.score_pl1) = *(param.score_pl1) + 1;
    }
    if (param.gameState->check_collision(param.player2) == true) {
        delete_xpos = param.player2->get_xpos();
        delete_ypos = param.player2->get_ypos();
        param.gameState->unset_chip_pos(delete_xpos, delete_ypos);
        handle_chip_deletion(delete_xpos, delete_ypos, param);
        *(param.score_pl2) = *(param.score_pl2) + 1;
    }
    if (param.gameState->check_empty_board() == true)
        handle_chip_creation(param.chip_coordinates, param.send_chip_creation, param.gameState);

    *(param.data) = packet.player_move;
    *(param.send_player_move) = true;
}

/*Listen_to_client forwards all the requests to the right function*/

void listen_to_client(listen_param param) {
    while (true) {
        sf::Packet packet;
        game_packet gamePacket;
        if (param.listener->receive(packet) != sf::Socket::Done)
            std::cout << "awaiting for input" << std::endl;
        packet >> gamePacket;
        if (gamePacket.type == PLAYER_MOVE_REQUEST)
            handle_plmove_request(gamePacket, param);
    }
}



int main()
{
    //--------------------------------Handles network connection
    sf::TcpListener listener_player1;
    sf::TcpListener listener_player2;

    if (listener_player1.listen(53005) != sf::Socket::Done) 
        std::cerr << "error binding player1 to the port" << std::endl;
    sf::TcpSocket client;
    if (listener_player1.accept(client) != sf::Socket::Done)
        std::cerr << "no connection" << std::endl;
    player player1(0,7);
    std::string player_number = "1";
    sf::Packet packet;
    packet << player1.get_xpos() << player1.get_ypos() << player_number;
    if (client.send(packet) != sf::Socket::Done)
        std::cout << "couldn't send packet" << std::endl;

    if (listener_player2.listen(53006) != sf::Socket::Done)
        std::cerr << "error binding player 2 to the sockect" << std::endl;
    sf::TcpSocket client2;
    if (listener_player2.accept(client2) != sf::Socket::Done)
        std::cerr << "no connection" << std::endl;
    player player2(7,7);
    player_number = "2";
    sf::Packet packet2;
    packet2 << player2.get_xpos() << player2.get_ypos() << player_number;
    if (client2.send(packet2) != sf::Socket::Done)
        std::cout << "couldn't send packet" << std::endl;
    //-----------------------------------------------------

    //--------------------------------------core variables
    game_state gameState; //Object that handles the current state of the game
    bool send_plmoveone = false;  //Triggers a request for player1 moves
    bool send_plmovetwo = false; //Triggers a request for player2 moves
    bool send_chip_deletion = false; //Triggers a request for chip_deletion
    bool send_chip_creation = false; //triggers a request for chip creation
    double chip_position_x;  //Variable used in the request context
    double chip_position_y; // variable used in the request context
    std::string chips_coordinates; // Variable used in the chip-creation request
    int score_pl1 = 0; // Current Score of  player1 after a request
    int score_pl2 = 0; // Current score of player2 after a request
    //-----------------------------------------

    std::cout << "sending chips coordinates" << std::endl;
    handle_chip_creation(&chips_coordinates, &send_chip_creation, &gameState);  

    std::string ins_player1;
    listen_param param_p1{ &client , &ins_player1, &send_plmoveone,
                          &send_chip_deletion,&send_chip_creation, 
                          &chip_position_x, &chip_position_y, 
                          &player1, &player2, &gameState , &chips_coordinates,
                          &score_pl1, &score_pl2};
    sf::Thread client_listener_thread_p1(&listen_to_client, param_p1);
    client_listener_thread_p1.launch();

    std::string ins_player2;
    listen_param param_p2{ &client2, &ins_player2, &send_plmovetwo,
                           &send_chip_deletion,&send_chip_creation, 
                           &chip_position_x, &chip_position_y, 
                           &player1, &player2, &gameState, &chips_coordinates,
                           &score_pl1, &score_pl2};
    sf::Thread client_listener_thread_p2(&listen_to_client, param_p2);
    client_listener_thread_p2.launch();


    while (true) {
        if (send_chip_creation == true) {
            sf::Packet packet;
            game_packet gamePacket{ CHIP_CREATION_REQUEST, chips_coordinates, 0 ,0};
            packet << gamePacket;
            std::cout << "sending coordinates" << chips_coordinates << std::endl;
            if (client.send(packet) != sf::Socket::Done)
                std::cout << "couldn't send packet" << std::endl;
            if (client2.send(packet) != sf::Socket::Done)
                std::cout << "couldn't send packet" << std::endl;
            send_chip_creation = false;
        }

        if (send_plmoveone == true) {
            sf::Packet packet;
            game_packet gamePacket{ PLAYER_MOVE_REQUEST, ins_player1, 0 , 0,
                                    player1.get_xpos(), player1.get_ypos(),
                                    player2.get_xpos(), player2.get_ypos(),
                                    score_pl1, score_pl2};
            packet << gamePacket;
            if (client.send(packet) != sf::Socket::Done)
                std::cout << "couldn't send packet" << std::endl;
            if (client2.send(packet) != sf::Socket::Done)
                std::cout << "couldn't send packet" << std::endl;
            send_plmoveone = false;
        }
        if (send_plmovetwo == true) {
            sf::Packet packet;
            game_packet gamePacket{ PLAYER_MOVE_REQUEST, ins_player1, 0 , 0,
                                    player1.get_xpos(), player1.get_ypos(),
                                    player2.get_xpos(), player2.get_ypos(),
                                    score_pl1, score_pl2};
            packet << gamePacket;
            if (client.send(packet) != sf::Socket::Done)
                std::cout << "couldn't send packet" << std::endl;
            if (client2.send(packet) != sf::Socket::Done)
                std::cout << "couldn't send packet" << std::endl;
            send_plmovetwo = false;
        }
        if (send_chip_deletion == true) {
            sf::Packet packet;
            game_packet gamePacket{CHIP_DELETION_REQUEST, "null", chip_position_x, chip_position_y};
            packet << gamePacket;
            if (client.send(packet) != sf::Socket::Done)
                std::cout << "couldn't send packet" << std::endl;
            if (client2.send(packet) != sf::Socket::Done)
                std::cout << "couldn't send packet" << std::endl;
            send_chip_deletion = false;
            chip_position_x = 0;
            chip_position_y = 0;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While I am not sure if it affects your implementation, I would suggest straying away from `rand` and `srand`. It's a good habit to get into so you don't have to change your implementation and/or coding habits later. Instead I would use something like `std::mt19937` and `std::uniform_int_distribution` (or `std::uniform_real_distribution`). For an example implementation, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13445752) SO answer could prove useful.

Answer (score 3):

**Item 1.**

Do not use magic numbers. If you max rand() value should be 56 - have a const variable with meaningful name.

**Item 2.**

If some variable is const - use const. Good candidate seems to be

```
std::string PLAYER_MOVE_REQUEST = "PLAYER_MOVE";
```

**Item 3.**

Pass parameters by reference not by pointer when you want to modify them

**Item4.**

Make function a member of the class/struct if it is logical part of class/struct interface. For example `handle_chip_deletion` asks to be made member of the listen_param

**Item 5.**

When you have group of logically bound variables - combine them into struct/class and then apply Item4. Like your set of `core variables` seems to be asking to be combined into Game class.

**Item 6.**

Your main seems to be too long and doing several things. One function - one thing. So separate your transport handling logic into one function and your game handling logic into another one at least.